# For which sahaba banana comes on Earth?

Tags: tafseer, history, sahaba

There is a history that banana comes from jannah to Earth  for a specific sahaba but I don't know the name of that sahaba

Comment: Fruits used to descend for umme eesa Mariam from heavens. I never read anything about companions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many interpretation of the Qur'an say that banana was referred to in verse ([56:29](https://legacy.quran.com/56/29)) this interpretation appears for example in the Sahih Internbational translation:

> And [banana] trees layered [with fruit]
>   <sub>Transliteration</sub> Watalhin mandood

This verse is referring to the gifts of those who were called the companions of the right, not necessarily or exclusively the sahabah (the companions of the prophet()).
You may find for example in tafsir ibn Kathir:

> Allah's said,
>   (and among Talh Mandud.)
>   refers to large thorny shrub that used to grow in the area of Hijaz (Western Arabia). Mujahid said that (Mandud) means:
>   "Its fruits are piled on top of each other. Allah is reminding the Quraysh of these kinds of trees, since they used to like the shade that the Talh and Sidr provided for them." Ibn Abi Hatim recorded that Abu Sa'id said that
>   (Talh Mandud) means: "The banana tree." And he (Ibn Abi Hatim) said, "Similar is reported from Ibn 'Abbas, Abu Hurayrah, Al-Hasan, `Ikrimah, Qasamah bin Zuhayr, Qatadah and Abu Hazrah. " Mujahid and Ibn Zayd said similalry, Ibn Zayd added, "The people of Yemen call the banana tree, Talh."
>   Ibn Jarir mentioned no other explanation for Talh. (Source: [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1655&Itemid=112))

Answer (score -1):

His name was Owais karni R.A ...who sacrificed all his teeth when our prophet's 1 teeth was sacrificed in the war